# What does the `--dev` flag do?

Tags: cli, dev

I get a different set of behaviors when running my node with `--dev` than when I run my node with my own custom setup.

What is happening in the background?

Answer (score 10):

When launching a chain with `--dev`, you are in the background enabling a specific set of CLI flags.

From the code comments:

```
/// This flag sets `--chain=dev`, `--force-authoring`, `--rpc-cors=all`,
/// `--alice`, and `--tmp` flags, unless explicitly overridden.
```

So, if you want to have a similar behavior to `--dev`, but using your own setup, keep in mind the flags above.

Comment: You mentioned code comments, but running `--help` on the substrate node might be a better way to access this and all the other flag definitions for the node. It has the same description for `--dev` given in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `--dev` flag ensures that the chain starts from genesis each time the process starts (This is what the `--tmp` flag does).

The other thing that can be handy is the compile time feature `--feature fast-runtime` which speeds up things like democracy so you don't have to wait the standard times (obviously this is only designed for test networks).

Comment: The `fast-runtime` feature is a custom Polkadot feature. This is nothing from Substrate. Any Substrate builder needs to create such a feature or just provide a different way to do this.

Comment: Good point. Important to make the distinction.